# Is there any way of running periodic fetch task in flutter IOS (fcm push notification is not receiving sometime)

Tags: flutter, flutter-workmanager

I tried workmanager package to run periodic task It works fine in android but for ios Its not running is there anything like Is it possible in native swift or c or Am I doing something wrong in ios side. I am looking for packges like cron and native timer.periodic but It oonly works if the app is in background.

A package or solution so that I can periodically do fetch from server and do operations like DB updation or run it few times in a day that can be prescheduled like an alarm manager or something just need to fetch and update DB in background every day with some delay the app can be in terminated state.

Comment: I believe on ios if the app is terminated the only way you can wake it up and execute code is to send a Firebase notification and have the user tap the notification.

Comment: Hello Bibek Saha, I am also suffering from a similar task. I had also done lots of R&D on this and I get that we can't do similar to Android in iOS when the application is terminated due to iOS OS restrictions. Once you terminate your app then the background process running Apple OS will destroy all threads which connect with the app.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Just to be sure terminate means swiping from recent app menu right?

Comment: Either the user or the OS can terminate an App.  The OS probably more often than you realize.